# Can you run gitk over SSH/SCP?

Tags: ssh, scp, gitk

I've started editing files over ssh/scp with vim, and it works pretty good.

So given that this can be done; is there any way to use SSH / SCP to load a remote repository into gitk locally?

I tried `gitk scp://root@192.168.XXX.XXX//home/demo` but I just end up with a dialog that reads `Cannot find a git repository here`.

Comment: I know I can just clone it locally...but...it seems like it would take less time if you could just leave the thing remote...maybe using an nfs share or something like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is not what you asked, it might help you:

You could simply mount it with [sshfs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,\
IdentityFile=/home/ysragh/.ssh/id_rsa \
yzzi@wow2d.development.yggdrasil.group:\
/opt/wow2d /home/ysragh/wow2d
```

And then you can use Vim and/or gitk in your home directory as if you downloaded it :)

I'm doing this like all the time when developing with virtual machine images :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can run the `gitk` on remote server, if you enable X11 Forwarding, if it is enabled and gitk installed on you server.

```
ssh -X root@192.168.XXX.XXX "cd /home/demo; gitk"
```

Comment: ya could...but that would just take up unnecessary space on your server.

Comment: It depends what is unnecessary on you use case.